How to understand $\nabla_i (\nabla_j f)=\nabla_i\nabla_j f$?
Picture below is from Chow and Knopf's The Ricci Flow: An Introduction. About the two red line, I have some doubts.  In this book,
$$
\nabla_i\nabla_j f  = (\partial_i\partial_j -\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k)f
\tag{1}
$$
Besides, for vector field $X=X^i\partial_i$,  I think $\nabla_X(f)=X^i\partial_i f$  (I have found no evidence for this in this book, but I think so.). Therefore, I think
$$
\nabla_i(\nabla_j f) =\partial_i \partial_j f \neq (\partial_i\partial_j -\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k)f = \nabla_i\nabla_j f
\tag{2}
$$
If treat $\nabla_j f$ as $\partial_j f dx^j$, seemly it  is ok. But this will obviously complicate the calculation.  For example, consider $\nabla_i (\nabla_j\nabla_k\nabla_l f)$.
On other hand, in 285th page, the authors write
$$
\nabla_X(\nabla_Y A) = \nabla_X \nabla_Y A +\nabla_{\nabla_XY}A
\tag{3}
$$
This makes me even more confused.




You should number your equations so that we can better pinpoint them. Your first equation is true because
$\nabla_jf$ is a covector by which its covariant derivative $\nabla_i\nabla_jf$ acquires a minus sign in front of the Christoffel symbol. When you think that it complicates the matters when you write that covector as a one form $\partial_jf,dx^j$ this is only a sign of the fact that you should study more of the basics.

Your second equation contains something completely wrong $\nabla_j(\nabla_if)$ is not $\partial_i\partial_j f,.$ Hint: $\partial_jf$ is the covector I talked about, or its components if someone prefers that nomenclature. Edit: I think Sean Carroll's book Spacetime and Geometry is something you should study before reading papers from the masters of Ricci flow.

One may understand $\nabla_j f$ as $df(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j})$, here $df\in T^*M$, so it is a function $TM\to \mathbb R$ (pointwise). Then one can view
$$
\nabla_i\nabla_jf=(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}df)\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\Big).
$$
For a $1$-form $\omega$, $\nabla_X\omega$ is also a $1$-form,
$(\nabla_X\omega)(Y)=X(\omega(Y))-\omega(\nabla_XY)$. Thus the above $\nabla_i\nabla_jf$ equals $\partial_i\partial_jf-df(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j})=\partial_i\partial_jf-\Gamma_{ij}^kf_k$.
In general, assume $A$ is a "$k$-tensor", i.e. at each point $p\in M$ as a multilinear map $(T_pM)^k \to \mathbb R$. One views $\nabla A$ as the $(k+1)$-tensor defined by
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla A(X_0, X_1, ..., X_k)=&\nabla_{X_0}A(X_1, ...,X_k)\\
=&X_0(A(X_1, ..., X_k))-
A(\nabla_{X_0}X_1, X_2, ...)-A(X_1, \nabla_{X_0}X_2, ...)-......
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, $\nabla_X\nabla_YA$ in the book shall be understood as the $k$-tensor
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla_X\nabla_YA(X_1, ...,X_k)=&
\nabla\nabla A(X, Y, X_1, ..., X_k)=\nabla_X\nabla A(Y, X_1, ..., X_k)\\
=&X(\nabla A(Y, X_1, ...,X_k))-\nabla A(\nabla_XY, X_1, ...)-\nabla A(Y, \nabla_XX_1, X_2, ...)-...\\
=&X(\nabla_Y A(X_1, ...,X_k))-\nabla_{\nabla_XY} A(X_1, ...)-\nabla_Y A( \nabla_XX_1, X_2, ...)-...\\
=& \nabla_X(\nabla_YA)(X_1, ...,X_k)-\nabla_{\nabla_XY} A(X_1, ...). 
\end{aligned}$$
Thus "$\nabla_X\nabla_YA=\nabla_X(\nabla_YA)-\nabla_{\nabla_XY} A$". Some people would write the "$\nabla_X\nabla_YA$" as $\nabla^2_{X, Y}A$ (I prefer this).
In the quoted text, one has to apply the RICCI IDENTITY
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2_{X, Y}A &(X_1, ... ,X_k)-\nabla^2_{Y, X}A(X_1, ..., X_k)\\
=&-A(R(X, Y)X_1, X_2, ...)-A(X_1, R(X, Y)X_2, ...)-...-A(X_1, ..., X_{k-1}, 
R(X, Y)X_k),
\end{aligned}$$
where $R(X, Y)V=\nabla_X\nabla_YV-\nabla_Y\nabla_XV-\nabla_{[X, Y]}V$ is the curvature - watch out this notation is negative to the curvature notation in the Chow-Knopf book (and Hamilton's papers and Schoen's papers).

Thanks, according your way, I calculate it. I treat $\nabla_i (R_{jk} \nabla_l f)$ as $\nabla(Ric\otimes df) (\partial_i, \partial_j, \partial_k, \partial_l)$. After calculate, it is $R_{jk} \nabla_i\nabla_l f  + \nabla_i R_{jk} \nabla_l f$. $\nabla_i$ like derivative.

But I'm always a little uneasy, because I haven't proven that the behave of $\nabla_i$ like a derivative. Besides, I can't catch the  motive of setting behavior of $\nabla_i$ be so complex.  Last, I think my problem is because I think the $()$ of $\nabla_X(\nabla_YA)$  is same with the $()$ of $\nabla_i (R_{jk} \nabla_l f)$. Seemly, only use $\nabla_X\nabla_Y A$ and $\nabla^2_{X,Y} A$ is suitable.

My English is not so good that I may not be able to express myself clearly. Anyway, I think I learned something from your answer. Thanks again.
